# How can I turn a string into a constraint (T-SQL)?

Tags: t-sql

In a reporting tool I want to show data using a predifined constraint. 
 
The constraint is stored in a table with 2 fields:  
Field 1 is called *Option* 
Field 2 is called *Constraint* 
 
For example: 
Option 1: 'ItemCode in (1,2,3) AND Status = 1' 
Option 2: 'ItemCode in (1,2,3) AND Status = 2' 
Option 3: 'ItemCode NOT in (1,2,3)'

The constraint is passed through as a paramater in a string format.
When the user selects option 1, the following select query should be executed: 
*Select * from Items where @Constraint* 
Which in this case should result in: 
*Select * from Items where ItemCode in (1,2,3) AND Status = 1* 
However, currently the statement looks like:
*Select * from Items where 'ItemCode in (1,2,3) AND Status = 1'*, which obviously doesn't work.

How can I get rid of these quotes and turn this string into a constraint, if possible at all?

Comment: Careful with terminology here... Your question concerns the [WHERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql) clause which could also be described as "field range" or "data filter", but has nothing to do with actual [SQL constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-table-constraint-transact-sql). Could you share the code that does the actual parameter replacement, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is generally called dynamic SQL. In SQL Server, you can construct a query in a string and then execute the query using either `sp_executesql` or `EXEC`. `sp_executesql` allows you to execute a query with paramaters, `EXEC` does not.

In your case, you would do something like:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(512);
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM items WHERE ';

SET @sql = @sql + @constraint;

EXEC @sql;
```

Please be aware that using dynamic SQL like this is one of the major ways that developers introduce SQL injection vulnerabilities. If `@constraint` is from a malicious source, it would be easy to make it `1=1; SELECT AllYourData FROM AllYourTables;` or worse.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If your set of predicates ("filters") is predefined and constant, you could just use logical operations in your where clause:

```sql
select   -- your columns 
from     Items
where    (@option = 1 and ItemCode in (1, 2, 3) and status = 1)
or       (@option = 2 and ItemCode in (1, 2, 3) and status = 2)
or       (@option = 3 and ItemCode not in (1, 2, 3));
--       .. and so on
```

You can of course keep adding more options.

Now, I realise you wanted to have your predefined filters in a table, but you also asked about making them constant. They can't be both, so what I have here is a solution for a set of constant predicates. I don't really see any advantage of storing them in a table in this case - they still have to be written down somewhere, might as well write them down directly inside the code rather than inside the table.

If you are putting this code into a stored procedure, an `option (recompile)` is a good idea. It tells SQL to generate a new plan which accounts for the actual value of `@constraint`, instead of using the stored plan. This is important when different values of `@constraint` could result in very different where clauses! Here is how to do that:

```sql
select   -- your columns 
from     Items
where    (@option = 1 and ItemCode in (1, 2, 3) and status = 1)
or       (@option = 2 and ItemCode in (1, 2, 3) and status = 2)
or       (@option = 3 and ItemCode not in (1, 2, 3))
--       .. and so on
option   (recompile);
```

On the other hand, if the predicates actually are not constant and you do need to put them in a table, then you would have to use dynamic sql. A common pattern is to add `where 1 = 1` to the constant part of the query string, because that way any additional conditions just get "anded". You don't need that here if you only ever want to apply a single predicate, but it's a nice trick to learn, so I'll show that:

```sql
-- constraint and option are keywords so you would have to use square backets for your column names.

declare @myquery varchar(max) = 'select * from Items where 1 = 1 ';

select @myquery = @myquery + ' and ' + [constraint]
from   FilterTable
where  [option] = @option;

exec (@myquery);
```